# Servlet's session MaxInactiveInterval setter and getter methods not working

Tags: servlets, session-timeout

Following is my code.

In this, 
session timeouts IMMEDIATELY, because  we’re saying, 
“timeout after 0  seconds of inactivity”.

Therefore the **session.getAttribute("foo")** must give an exception. But the code works without glitch as if the session did not **timeout** at all.

```
 public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
                                                           throws IOException {
         response.setContentType(“text/html”);
         PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
         HttpSession session = request.getSession();
         session.setAttribute(“foo”, “42”);
         session.setMaxInactiveInterval(0);
         String foo = (String) session.getAttribute(“foo”);
         if (session.isNew()) {
            out.println(“This is a new session.”); 
          } else {
            out.println(“Welcome back!”);
        }
        out.println(“Foo: “ + foo);
 }
```

Similar is the problem when I use **getMaxInactiveInterval()**.

It gives correct result when I first call **setMaxInactiveInterval()** explicitly. But when it's not set programmatically, **getMaxInactiveInterval** doesn't show default session timeout which is 30 minutes. Instead it always gives **60 seconds** as its result.

My Server is Apache Tomcat 7.
Thanks for the help

Comment: what's the point in setting something in the session and get it without processing the response???

Comment: The code was explained in HeadFirst JSP and Servlet Book to show the semantics of Session's methods. Therefore, please pardon me the lack of logic, if any, from application's point of view, Sir. Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
     session.setMaxInactiveInterval(0);
```

By docs

> Specifies the time, in seconds, between client requests before the servlet container will invalidate this session.
>   An interval value of zero or less indicates that the session should never timeout.
>   Parameters:
>   interval - An integer specifying the number of seconds

So if you put it to zero iti will never time out. if you try with

```
         session.setMaxInactiveInterval(10);
```

it will expire after 10 seconds. Be aware that there is a value also in the web.xml which represents the timeout in minutes, wrt to the one that you set programmatically which is an interval expressed in seconds.

Comment: Sir, I had checked this with value 1 seconds before posting this question. Then I invoked sleep(1200) method on the servlet's Thread so that session may timeout, even then, it's not working. With getMaxInactiveInterval(), I had considered those web.xml factors too. Thanks for the answer, Sir.

Comment: don't set the sleep time. you have to refresh the page within 10 seconds and you will see that you load old session and after 10 seconds so that you see the session is a new one. try this way please and you will understand what's happening

Answer (score 3):

Tomcat expires sessions using a background thread. By default that thread only checks sessions for expiration once a minute.

If `getMaxInactiveInterval()` doesn't return the default of 1800 (30 minutes) then something, somewhere has changed the default.

Comment: I wish I could accept your answer too... Because your answer too has guided me towards correct understanding on the topic. Anyways, let me search for the answers you've given to others. I'll upvote you on those helpful answers (definitely there'll be plenty of those) of yours. I owe you big time, Sir...